# can we use access token generated through any mobile app for a facebook user for another web api to access the user 's data?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access users photo using web app for facebook.But the access token for the user will be generated by a mobile app.Is it possible to use that in web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,Its possible ,it doesn't matter where the access token has been generated .We can use the same access token to get use'rs data as per the provided permissions .